# Geometric interpretation of affine subspaces in projection method

Tags: projection

In Jousef Saad's book (see ref.1), the author introduces the projection method capable of solving a large set of linear system of equations iteratively.

Below is what extracted from the book about the method:

> For linear system of equations
> $$\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{b}$$
> where
> $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $\boldsymbol{x}$ is the
> vector of solution ($\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$).
>
> A **projection method** onto $\mathcal{K}_m$ and orthogonal to
> $\mathcal{L}_m$ is a process which finds an approximate solution
> $\tilde{\boldsymbol{x}}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ satisfying
>
> $$ \mathrm{Find\ } \tilde{\boldsymbol{x}}\in \mathcal{K}_m,\quad
>  \mathrm{such\ that}\quad  \boldsymbol{b} -\boldsymbol{A}\tilde{\boldsymbol{x}} \bot \mathcal{L}_m  $$ where
> $\mathcal{K}_m$ and $\mathcal{L}_m$ are two $m$-dimensional subspace
> of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($m \leqslant  n$), which are termed the **search
> subspace** and the **constraint subspace**, respectively.
>
> Given an initial guess $\boldsymbol{x_0}$ to the solution, the
> approximation must be sought in an **affine space**
> $\boldsymbol{x_0}+\mathcal{K}_m$ instead of the homogeneous vector
> space $\mathcal{K}_m$.
>
> $$ \mathrm{Find\ } \tilde{\boldsymbol{x}}\in \boldsymbol{\tilde{x}_0} + \mathcal{K}_m,\quad \mathrm{such\ that}\quad  \boldsymbol{b} - \boldsymbol{A}\tilde{\boldsymbol{x}} \bot \mathcal{L}_m  $$

To clarify my question below, I take a low-dimensional case in the 3-D cubic
space ($n = 3$, $m = 2$) as an example and sketch a
illustration:

[Illustration of subspaces of a 3-D space in the projection method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4ANe.png)

**Questions**:

1. What is the geometric significance of the **affine space**
   $\boldsymbol{x_0}+\mathcal{K}_m$, or how does it look like in the
   cubic?
2. What is the spatial relationship between $\mathcal{K}_m$ and
   the **affine space** $\boldsymbol{x_0}+\mathcal{K}_m$ in the cubic?

**Reference**:

*Saad, Yousef*, 2003, Iterative methods for sparse linear systems., Philadelphia, PA: SIAM Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics. xviii, p. 134 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our usual cubic (3D) space, a two-dimensional subspace is the same thing as an infinite plane that contains a specified point (the origin). A general plane that does not necessarily contain the origin is a two-dimensional affine space. One can always get an affine space by taking a subspace parallel to it and displacing it by some vector. Ignoring all the math jargon, $\mathcal{K}_m$ is a plane containing the origin and $\pmb{x_0} + \mathcal{K}_m$ is the plane parallel to $\mathcal{K}_m$ containing the point $\pmb{x_0}$.